How to fix react.js home page authorization running before the JWT cookie is set?
I've been coding a blog post application in React and now I am trying to add authentication and authorization to the app using JWT tokens ( using the Jsonwebtoken npm library ). And I am using node js backend.
The workflow is this way, Sign Up > Home Page ( This is where the problem occurs )
Problem

The sign up page registers the user and returns  a json token as 'jwt' which is stored in the cookie.
And successfull registration redirects me to the homepage where I check for authorization inside useEffect by checking if the cookie is set or not.
But this part of my homepage code,

if (!cookies.jwt) {
navigate('/signUp');
            }

always seem to jump me back to the signUp page

After some experimenting, I found out that the JWT cookie is being set slower than the time it takes for redirecting the user, so by the time I am in the homepage the cookie hasn't been set yet.
But I am able to come back to homepage manually and access it with successful authorization.

This is my firs time posting a question on Stackoverflow, sorry if I hadn't given enough information, I've tried my best. Feel free to ask me for more information.
Sign Up Code:
import BookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Book';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Avatar, Box, Container, CssBaseline, Typography, TextField, Grid, Link, Button, FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Toaster, toast } from 'sonner';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';




function SignUp() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [signUpStatus, setsignUpStatus] = useState("");
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target.email.value;
        const password = e.target.password.value;
        const signUpPostRequest = async () => {
            const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register', { email: email, password: password }, {
                withCredentials: true,
            }).then(async (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.data) { setsignUpStatus('Signed Up!'); }
                navigate('/homepage');
                console.log('hi');
            }).catch((data) => {
                const responseMsg = data;
                console.log(responseMsg);
                setsignUpStatus(responseMsg);
            });
        }
        setsignUpStatus("Signing Up...");
        signUpPostRequest();
    }
    const customTheme = createTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: {
                light: '#757ce8',
                main: '#31363F',
                dark: '#222831',
                contrastText: '#fff',
            },
            secondary: {
                light: '#EEEEEE',
                main: '#31363F',
                dark: '#222831',
                contrastText: '#000',
            },
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
            <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
                <Container component="main" maxWidth='xs'>
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Box sx={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        display: "flex",
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}>
                        <Avatar sx={{
                            m: 1,
                            color: "secondary.light",
                            bgcolor: "primary.dark"
                        }}>
                            <BookIcon
                            //  color="grey"
                            ></BookIcon>
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography align="center" component="h1" variant="h5">Sign Up</Typography>

                        <Box component="form"
                            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                            sx={{
                                mt: 1
                            }}>
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal" required id="email" label="Email" name="email" variant="standard" fullWidth></TextField>
                            <TextField
                                margin="normal" required id="password" label="Password" name="password" variant="standard" fullWidth
                            ></TextField>

                            <FormControlLabel sx={{
                                // mt: 1,
                            }}
                                control={
                                    <Checkbox label="remember"></Checkbox>
                                }
                                label="Remember me"
                            />
                            <Button type="submit"
                                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                                variant="contained" fullWidth>Sign Up</Button>
                            <Grid container>
                                <Grid item xs>
                                    <Link href="./"
                                        underline="none" variant="body2">
                                        {"Already have an account? Sign In"}
                                    </Link>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    {/* <Link
                                        underline="none" href="#"
                                        variant="body2">
                                        Forgot password?
                                    </Link> */}
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Box element="div">
                                <Typography>
                                    {signUpStatus}
                                </Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Container>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </>
    )
}

export default SignUp;

Homepage code:
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
// import SimpleBackdrop from './backdropComp'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// import HomePageContent from './HomePageContent'
import HomePageContent from './HomePageCotent'
import AppBarComp from './AppBarComp'
import { Adb as AdbIcon, Menu as MenuIcon, Book as BookIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Avatar, Box, Container, CssBaseline, Typography, TextField, Grid, Link, Button, FormControlLabel, Checkbox, AppBar, IconButton, Tooltip, MenuItem, Menu, Toolbar } from '@mui/material';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';


var blogContent = "Be subject to all the higher powers; for there is no power but of God: now those which are have been ordained of God. Romans 13:1 And again, in reference to them he says, For he bears not the sword in vain; for he is the minister of God, the avenger for wrath to him who does evil. Romans 13:4 Now, that he spoke these words, not in regard to angelical powers, nor of invisible rulers — as some venture to expound the passage — but of those of actual human authorities, [he shows when] he says, For this cause pay tribute also: for they are God's ministers, doing service for this very thing.";
blogContent = blogContent.length > 500 ? blogContent.substring(0, 500) + "..." : blogContent

function HomePage() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([]);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(cookies);
        const authorizaUser = async () => {
            if (!cookies.jwt) {
                navigate('/signUp');
            }
            const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/', {
                withCredentials: true
            }).then(({ data }) => {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.isExpired) {
                    console.log(data.message, data.data);
                    var posts = data.data.map((element, index) =>
                    <HomePageContent key={element._id} postTitle={element.postTitle} postContent={element.postContent} />
                    )
                    setPosts(posts);
                    return
                }
            }).catch(({ response }) => {
                console.log(response.data.message);
                if (response.data.isExpired) navigate('/');
                return
            })
        }
        authorizaUser()
    }, [cookies, removeCookie, navigate])

    // authorization();
    return (
        <>
            <AppBarComp />
            {posts}
        </>
    )
}

export default HomePage;

Node.js controller for both the sign-up and home-page of client:
localhost:3000/register (POST) - To register the user and direct him to homepage
async function registerController(req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log('Email: ' + email + ' Password: ' + password);
    await userModel.create({ username: email, password: password, posts: [{ postTitle: "kjlj", postContent: "lkjlkj" }] }).then(async (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const id = data._id;
        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, 'bar', { expiresIn: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 });
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            withCredentials: true,
            httpOnly: false,
            maxAge: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        });
        await res.status(200).json({
            userId: data._id,
            message: "Registered the user!",
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        if (err.code == 11000) {
            res.status(403).json({
                message: "Email ID should be unique"
            })
        }
        console.log(err);
        console.log("error exists");
    })
}


localhost:3000/ (GET) - To authorize everytime the user comes to the homepage
async function homeController(req, res, next) {
    // Finding the posts of user, while authorizing their request also
    async function getPosts({ id }) {
        await userModel.findOne({ _id: id }).then((data) => {
            // console.log(data.posts);
            res.status(200).json({
                isExpired: false,
                message: "Token is still valid",
                data: data.posts
            })
            return
        })
    }
    authorize(req, res, { operation: getPosts, test: 1 });
}

I tried to authorize the homepage page it seems to redirect me back to the signUp page due to the fact that the cookie after registering is being set slower than the reaction time it's taking for redirection to homepage.

In general, this is called a race condition. Usually with race conditions (which kudos on determining that part) it's best to break things down and make things clean. In your code, you are combining both async/await and .then/catch continuations. Pick one (I'd go with async/await). Also smaller, clearly named functions might provide overall clarity. In this particular case, signUpPostRequest looks async but is not awaited inside an async handler handleSubmit.

Thank you so much. I clearly had some misconceptions about async and then(), catch() techniques. I replaced the then(), catch() with try and catch statements and now it works flawlessly.
I still don't fully understand why your instructions worked, but this makes me realise I need to go study the basics of async functions, promise, then() catch() techniques.
Anyhow, I managed to fix the race condition as it was pointed out by you with your instructions.
How do I make your comment to be my answer? I am new to stackoverflow.

Cool! Of course, with race conditions, it may be that just now -- because of some timing differences with using all async/await -- that it just looks like it's working. I think it would probably be best for you to post your fixed code as your own answer and mark it as the answer. This way we can have some clarity on exactly the changes that fixed your code which might help others. In general clarity in code, clarity in questions are a good thing. You can upvote my comment(s) as well. And welcome to SO!

I've posted my answer and SO doesn't let me upvote your comment. I think I can only upvote answers and not comments.

I've finally got the solution from wraiford in my problem's comment section.
Just like he pointed out, I refactored my code with proper usage of asynchronous techniques, whereas before, I was using both await and .then() on the Axios post/get request which I believe was causing this phenomenon called race condition, as also pointed out by wraiford. So I properly this time, used try and catch blocks and used only await statement for handling the Axios requests asynchronously.
Here's what I did differently than before that fixed my problem,
SignUp page, handleSubmit function
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target.email.value;
    const password = e.target.password.value;
    setsignUpStatus("Signing Up...");

    try {
        const responseData = await signUpPostRequest(email, password);
        console.log(responseData);
        console.log(cookies);
        setsignUpStatus('Signed Up!');
        navigate('/homepage')
        // Navigate or perform any other action upon successful signup
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setsignUpStatus("Error: " + error.message);
    }
}

const signUpPostRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/register', { email, password }, {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error.response.data || error.message;
    }
}

Homepage, useEffect, authorizeUser function
useEffect(() => {
    const authorizaUser = async () => {
        if (!cookies.jwt) {
            navigate('/signUp');
            return
        }
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/', {
                withCredentials: true
            })
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.isExpired) {
                console.log(data.message, data.data);
                var posts = data.data.map((element, index) =>
                    <HomePageContent key={element._id} postTitle={element.postTitle} postContent={element.postContent} />
                )
                setPosts(posts);
                return
            }
        }
        catch ({ response }) {
            console.log(response.data.message);
            if (response.data.isExpired) navigate('/');
            return
        }
    }
    authorizaUser();
}, [cookies, removeCookie, navigate])


Looks clearer to me! And hopefully to your future you when you go back to maintain the code. Btw the only other thing that pops out at me that isn't necessarily related to your race condition is the throw error.response.data || error.message; part. If you are unsure of the shape of the error object (a common thing in JS), it's good to use "optional chaining". Your current code if will throw if error.response is ever falsy. Right now there is only the one post call, but if post changes internally or you add more code in the try block, this may change which could be a pain.
